# Calculating standard errors for groups with heteroskedasticity

Tags: r, standard-error

I'm attempting to calculate the standard error (SE) of several experimental groups for the purpose of making a plot. However, the data do not satisfy homogeneity of variances- the difference in variance of fitness between treatments is quite large and cannot be solved by the transformations I've tried.

My model is pretty simple: `Fitness ~ History * Treatment`.

In R, I've tried using `emmeans` with my model as an lm, and that gives the exact same SE for each group as expected, since it assumes homogeneity of variances. I've read that the gls function of the package `nlme` should solve this issue [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369532/interpreting-the-standard-error-from-emmeans-r) by allowing heterogeneity of variances, but even running `emmeans` on `nlme::gls()` gives extremely similar SE among groups (below).

```
> SM2 <- gls(Seed_mass_mg~History*Treatment, data1, na.action = na.omit)
emmeans(SM2, ~History * Treatment)
 History   Treatment emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 ancestral drought     35.0 5.93 909     23.3     46.6
 dry       drought     56.3 6.29 909     44.0     68.7
 wet       drought     39.1 6.12 909     27.1     51.1
 ancestral watered    102.9 6.02 909     91.1    114.8
 dry       watered    131.0 6.38 909    118.5    143.6
 wet       watered    140.2 5.97 909    128.4    151.9

Degrees-of-freedom method: df.error 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

However, when I calculate the SE by formula I get quite different SE:

```
History     Treatment   Seed_mass_mg_SE
Ancestral   Watered     7.008392
Ancestral   Drought     1.60024
Drought     Watered     8.693766
Drought     Drought     2.740732
Watered     Watered     9.229806
Watered     Drought     2.234901
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm misunderstanding about SE here?

Comment: Use `by`, `tapply`, or a `data.table` summary, among other solutions.

Comment: It wasn't emmeans that imposed that, it was you. If you were using lm(), you already tossed in an assumption of homogeneity. If you want it model-based, use a model that supports heterogeneity, e.g., nome::gls(). See the FAQs vignette in emmeans for a bit more info.

Comment: @whuber I strongly disagree with your reason for closing this. It really is a misunderstanding of statistical models, not coding, that is at the crux of this. See my comment above.

Comment: @Russ You could be right, but you seem to be reading an awful lot into this question.  The text currently demands a specific `R` calculation.  If it were edited by the OP to support your interpretation I would be among the first to vote to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Russ and @whuber! I edited my question for clarification, as I was already using 'nlme::gls()' yet still having this problem. Also, 'by' and 'tapply' can't calculate SE, but could be used to calculate the standard deviation and then divide by the square root of the sample size. Since this is the same as calculating SE directly by formula would there be an advantage to using the standard deviation calculated using 'by' or 'tapply', versus that calculated using 'sd()'?

Comment: On the contrary, `by` and `tapply` can apply any function to the grouped data, including a function to compute the SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `gls()` call without a `weights` argument is just like a `lm()` call, because it defaults to a homoscedastic model. In particular, I suggest adding `weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | History*Treatment)`. See the documentation for `varIdent`, and take another look at that [FAQs vignette in **emmeans**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html#nowelch).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! It was difficult to understand, but I got the weights argument working. The final model I used is: test3 <- gls(Seed_mass_mg~History+Treatment + History:Replicate + History:Treatment, data1, na.action = na.omit, weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | Treatment))